# data in included views in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my laravel app, I am passing a variable $data to a view which I will later include in another view. So in my controller method, I have:

```
public function random($id){
    $data = DB::table('reports')->where('id',$id);
    return view('partials.data', compact('data'));
}
```

In the `partials.data` I have:

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'reports/data',$id]) !!}

    <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed table-bordered tab-content">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Month</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($data as $dat)
                <tr>{{$dat->month}}</tr>
                <tr>{{$dat->value}}</tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And in the main view I have this function:

```
function kpi_values(d) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    kpi = d.id;
    return '@include("reports.data", array("id" => "kpi"))';
}
```

Which is triggered by:

```
$('#monthly_table tbody').on('click', 'td.details-controls', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row(tr);
        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            row.child(kpi_values(row.data())).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');


        }
    });
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
ErrorException in 3534c4c98c65c2d5267bf7c54a960d41 line 13:
Undefined variable: data
```

I have passed the variable data in my partial view, however, it seems like it requires it in the primary view.

Is there any way of doing this without passing the variable to the primary view? I don't want to mix things because the partial view controller method requires a parameter, while the primary view has no parameters in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel offers a great tool to handle this situation in which we need to pass some parameters to partial views without passing through the primary view. That is view composer. Here is an example :

```
In \App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php file

public function boot()
{

    //get data and pass it to partials.data whenever partials.data is executed

 view()->composer('partials.data',function($view){
   $view->with('data',DataSet::all());
 });  

}
```

For more advanced, you can learn it from [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/25)

Comment: i have another question. what if instead of `DataSet::all()` i had something like `DB::table('reports')->where('id',$id)`, how do i pass the `$id` parameter to the service provider?

Comment: That's a little bit long answer. You should make a new question segment. I will answer it for you. Give me a link when you create it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31277017/passing-variables-to-laravel-service-provider/31278085#31278085 here is the question

Answer (score 0):

You may use share methods to pass the data to all views.

```
return view('partials.data')->share('data', $data);
```