# passing variables to laravel service provider

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to pass a variable on my laravel app from the view to the service provider.
The view is:

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'reports/data',$kpi_id]) !!}

    <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed table-bordered tab-content">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Month</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($data as $dat)
                <tr>{{$dat->month}}</tr>
                <tr>{{$dat->value}}</tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

and the code at the service provider is:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->composeData();
}

/**
 * Register the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //
}

public function composeData()
{
    view()->composer('reports.data', function ($view, $id) {
        $view->with('data', DB::table('reports')->where('kpi_id', $id)->orderBy('month', 'desc')->take(5)->get());
    });
}
```

The error:

```
Argument 2 passed to App\Providers\DataServiceProvider::App\Providers\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Http\Requests\Request, none given
```

I tried it with Request but still didn't manage to make it work.

I want to know how to pass the variable from the view to the service provider, or at least how to call the controller method from the service provider. I tried it but failed to make it work. All the help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

I get the `$id` from a `var` variable in the view

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you pass $id through a route, using `Router` class which is very useful in this case. For example :

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Router; // include in your ServiceProvider

public function boot(Router $router)
{
    $router->bind('id',function($id){ // route:  /reports/{id}
        $this->composeData($id);
    });
}

public function composeData($id)
{
  $result = DB::table('reports')->where('kpi_id', $id)->orderBy('month', 'desc')->take(5)->get()

   view()->composer('reports.data', function ($view) use ($result) {
    $view->with('data', $result);
});
}
```

But be carefull, now your view is depend on {id} parameter.

Comment: does this cause the page to be redirected? because this is intended to be a partial view

Comment: what you try to do is making a request from the client ( which is view) to the server ( which is ServiceProvider ). If you don't want to leave your view when requesting data, you can use Ajax call. That's a different story.

Comment: i want the partial view to change, but not the other part. and i haven't tried ajax on laravel. however that method still gave me the undefined variable data

Comment: Searching for Ajax working with partial view. I think there will be answers out there. Good luck !

Answer (score -2):

I don't know where you are getting id from so I'm assuming it's stored somewhere in the request object.  With that said, you can type-hint the request object in the service provider's constructor.  Then pass the id into the callback function via the `use` keyword.

```
public function __construct($app, \Request $request)
{
    parent::__construct($app);

    $this->request = $request;
}

public function boot()
{
    $this->composeData();
}

/**
 * Register the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //
}

public function composeData()
{
    $id = $this->request->get('your_id');
    view()->composer('reports.data', function ($view) use($id) {
        $view->with('data', \DB::table('reports')->where('kpi_id', $id)->orderBy('month', 'desc')->take(5)->get());
    });
}
```

Comment: this throws `Argument 1 passed to App\Providers\DataServiceProvider::__construct() must be an instance of Request, instance of Illuminate\Foundation\Application given,`

Comment: Oh I see, the parent class is expecting to receive `Illuminate\Foundation\Application`.  I've updated the answer, hopefully that works for you.

Comment: it gives me another error similar to the first one. `Argument 2 passed to App\Providers\DataServiceProvider::__construct() must be an instance of Request, none given`